# transfer the custom ringtones

Tags: ios

I have custom ringtones on my iPhone5s which show in Tones on iTunes. They were originally setup years ago on older iTunes.

I am trying to setup an older iPhone5c and would like to transfer the custom ringtones, but can't seem to find how.

Comment: Do you see them in the iPhone part of iTunes (where the content of your iPhone is shown)? AFAIK you can‘t transfer them back to your Mac from there

Answer (score 1):

I found the original on my Mac.

There seemed to be no means of selecting in iTunes, so I tried (shudder) dragging the file to iTunes which worked.